# how to execute two functions in a cloud function in GCP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to run a function which is inside a function of Cloud function in GCP. I've put the second function inside if loop by giving a condition. Even though my if condition satisfies, my second function is not running. I replaced the entire second function i.e., df_load_function with a print statement and deployed the code. This is working fine that means print statement is showing results in the output.

So why the "df_load_function" function is not running even after if condition getting satisfied ?

If I deploy "df_load_function" in an another cloud function it is working fine. But I've a requirement to run the "df_load_function" only if a file that starts with "inbound/DL_Ticket_" hits the cloud storage bucket. And this is a daily incremental file whose name changes everyday.
Can someone please help me in achieving this ?

Below is my code :

```
from google.cloud import storage
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import time
import os

def mv_blob(bucket_name, blob_name):
 client = storage.Client()
 bucket_name = "standard"
 bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)
 blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix='inbound/DL_Ticket_'))
 for blob in blobs:
  blob_name = blob.name
  print("{}.".format(blob_name))
  if blob_name != '':
    def df_load_function(file, context):
        filesnames = [
            'DL_Customer_',
            'DL_RegisteredProducts_',
            'DL_Ticket_'
            ]

        for i in filesnames:
            if 'inbound/{}'.format(i) in file['name']:
                print("Processing file: {filename}".format(filename=file['name']))

                project = 'nonprod'
                inputfile = 'gs://standard/inbound/' + file['name']
                job = 'df_load_wave1_{}'.format(i)
                template = 'gs://standard/template/df_load_wave1_{}'.format(i)
                location = 'asia-south1'
           
                dataflow = build('dataflow', 'v1b3', cache_discovery=False)
                request = dataflow.projects().locations().templates().launch(
                    projectId=project,
                    gcsPath=template,
                    location=location,
                    body={
                        'jobName': job,
                        "environment": {
                        "workerZone": "asia-south1-a"
                    }
                    }
                )

            # Execute the dataflowjob
                response = request.execute()
            
                job_id = response["job"]["id"]
```

Comment: You probably want to define function first, and then just call it inside an if statement

Comment: It's giving me this error "TypeError: df_load_function() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'file' and 'context' " when I call it inside if statement. Can you help me what arguments I need to provide during the function call.

Comment: You don't seem to use context anywhere so it can be safely deleted. The file argument is probably a dictionary but you just use one entry from it 'name' (is it like a container, or file name?). I would change it to just string and use it instead.

Comment: I tried giving the following arguments and got errors as below 
==> 'name' - TypeError: string indices must be integers.
==> name  - NameError: name 'name' is not defined
==> file['name'] - NameError: name 'file' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, just replace the "test" string with your desired value

```
from google.cloud import storage
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import time
import os

def mv_blob(bucket_name, blob_name):
 client = storage.Client()
 bucket_name = "standard"
 bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)
 blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix='inbound/DL_Ticket_'))
 for blob in blobs:
  blob_name = blob.name
  print("{}.".format(blob_name))
  if blob_name != '':
    df_load_function({"name": "test"})

def df_load_function(file):
    filesnames = [
        'DL_Customer_',
        'DL_RegisteredProducts_',
        'DL_Ticket_'
        ]

    for i in filesnames:
        if 'inbound/{}'.format(i) in file['name']:
            print("Processing file: {filename}".format(filename=file['name']))

            project = 'nonprod'
            inputfile = 'gs://standard/inbound/' + file['name']
            job = 'df_load_wave1_{}'.format(i)
            template = 'gs://standard/template/df_load_wave1_{}'.format(i)
            location = 'asia-south1'
        
            dataflow = build('dataflow', 'v1b3', cache_discovery=False)
            request = dataflow.projects().locations().templates().launch(
                projectId=project,
                gcsPath=template,
                location=location,
                body={
                    'jobName': job,
                    "environment": {
                    "workerZone": "asia-south1-a"
                }
                }
            )

        # Execute the dataflowjob
            response = request.execute()
        
            job_id = response["job"]["id"]
```

Comment: Actually I cannot provide any constant value because am putting this code in a google cloud function and the trigger is the daily incremental files which starts with the names present in the filenames list.  All the files present in the filenames list hits our cloud storage bucket everyday. So how can I provide a single value as an argument ?

Comment: So for what are you using the "file" variable? From the code i assume that you want to choose all files from inbound container that starts with filenames list, so why are you using also "file" variable

Comment: If I don't declare the "file" variable in the function, I'm getting this error "NameError: name 'file' is not defined". And if I remove the file variable in my code inside for loop, it's not working as expected. My requirement is when any of the file which is present in the filenames hits cloud storage bucket it should trigger a dataflow pipeline code. I've created template for the pipelines code for each file. And based on the file which is uploaded, respective dataflow template should run. I've provided Dataflow template names and the file names are same.

Comment: And one more main condition is, all the dataflows should run only if "DL_Ticket_" file is present in inbound folder. Otherwise nothing should run.

Comment: so what are you trying to check in this `if 'inbound/{}'.format(i) in file['name']`

Comment: this will check the file if the file which is uploaded in inbound is present list in filenames, it will enter the loop.

Comment: Do you even know what your code does? In line 10 ` blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix='inbound/DL_Ticket_'))`  you extract all files that start with DL_Ticket, so why you insist on checking it again? I think you just copied two random functions from some example and don't even know what they are doing.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I want to check if the 'inbound/DL_Ticket_' file is present in inbound. If it is present, then only I have to enter the if loop and need to run the respective dataflow templates of each file in inbound. That's why I'm checking the files again. Btw I'm writing the code in my way and if it's not working then I will search for the resources possible to find a solution. May be you call it as copy which all the developers do in their daily life.